# Error with using sort on type a in Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell

I am pretty new to Haskell and I am trying to write a function `neighbours :: Int -> Metric a -> Point a -> [Point a] -> [Point a]` such that `neighbours k d p xs` returns a list of the k nearest neighbours, in distance order, according to metric d to point p in the list xs of points. My code is

```
type Point a = (a, a)
type Metric a = Point a -> Point a -> Double
type Tuple a = (Double, Point a)

create:: Metric a -> Point a -> [Point a] ->  [Tuple a] -> [Tuple a]
create d p (x:xs) ys | length xs == 0 = sort(((d p x), x) : ys)
                     | otherwise      = create d p xs (((d p x), x) : ys)

takeP:: Tuple a -> Point a
takeP (_,p) = p   

pList::  [Tuple a] ->[Point a]-> [Point a]
pList (x:xs) ys | length xs == 0 = reverse (takeP x : ys)
                | otherwise      = pList xs (takeP x : ys) 

neighbours :: Int -> Metric a -> Point a -> [Point a] -> [Point a]--
neighbours k d p xs = take k (pList (create d p xs []) [])
```

But I am getting an error on sort which is:

```
* No instance for (Ord a) arising from a use of `sort'
  Possible fix:
    add (Ord a) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        create :: forall a.
                  Metric a -> Point a -> [Point a] -> [Tuple a] -> [Tuple a]
* In the expression: sort (((d p x), x) : ys)
  In an equation for `create':
      create d p (x : xs) ys
        | length xs == 0 = sort (((d p x), x) : ys)
        | otherwise = create d p xs (((d p x), x) : ys)
```

I used `type Point a = (Int, Int)` at first and it was working fine but in the specification it is required that Point is `type Point a = (a, a)` which caused my error. The other problem is that I cannot change the function types so I can't just add `(Ord a)` as proposed.

Is there a way to sort the Tuples' list by the first variable without encountering errors?

Comment: Since you `sort` on `((d p x), x) : ys`, you need to add a type constraint to `create`, so `create:: Ord a => Metric a -> Point a -> [Point a] ->  [Tuple a] -> [Tuple a]`.

Comment: Also beware that `length xs` is not a good idea here, since it takes linear time, you can make use of `null xs` instead.

Comment: Adding `Ord a =>` would require adding it also to `neighbours` which would change the desired function type which is  `neighbours :: Int -> Metric a -> Point a -> [Point a] -> [Point a]`

Comment: Thanks for the note on `length xs`

Comment: yes, of course the type constraints are transitive. If you only want to sort on the `Double`, you can use `sortOn fst` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `create` function, you make use of [**`sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sort):

```
… = sort (((d p x), x) : ys)
```

this thus means that type of objects that we are sorting, in this case `Tuple a`, needs to be an instance of the `Ord` typeclass. A 2-tuple is an instance of the `Ord` typeclass, if both the type of the items are instances of `Ord` as well, so in this case `Double` and `Point a`. Since `Point a` is also a 2-tuple, but of two `a`s, this thus means that `Tuple a` is an instance of `Ord`, if `a` is an instance of `Ord`. You thus should add a type constraint:

```
create :: Ord a => Metric a -> Point a -> [Point a] ->  [Tuple a] -> [Tuple a]
create d p (x:xs) ys | length xs == 0 = sort(((d p x), x) : ys)
                     | otherwise      = create d p xs (((d p x), x) : ys)
```

The `create` function makes use of some anti-patterns like using `length`, which takes linear time. You can in fact rewrite this to sorting a mapping:

```
create :: Ord a => Metric a -> Point a -> [Point a] -> [Tuple a]
create d p = sort . map f
    where f x = (d p x, x)
```

This removes the `ys` parameter, which here only seems to be used as a accumulator.

If you wish to only sort on the first item of the 2-tuple, you can make use of [**`sortOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn):

```
create :: Metric a -> Point a -> [Point a] -> [Tuple a]
create d p = sortOn fst . map f
    where f x = (d p x, x)
```

Comment: I used your suggestion on the `create` function and added `Ord a =>` where necessary and it seems that the automated test does not complain on adding `Ord a =>` to the function type and the tests were passed so I guess it works fine. Thank you for the quick reply.